# Wording of close reason off-topic as "problems facing undergraduate students" seems not ideal

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

I realize that there is always an 'Other' option, allowing to specify why one believes a question should be closed. However, there is a reason why boilerplate suggestions are used - to streamline the process and keep it less subjective. Looking at [this obviously off-topic question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55970/which-job-is-better-for-future), it seems that the intent is to choose off-topic reason 1 whose implied meaning appears to be "the question is not about graduate studies." However, the text states that questions about *undergraduate studies* are off-topic. Wouldn't it be more useful and precise to change the wording to what it, I think, stands for - questions not about graduate level education are off-topic?

In the current infrastructure, what is this site's suggested closing reason here and in similar cases? I realize the question is certainly also opinion-based; but that appears to be secondary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> questions not about graduate level education are off-topic

That's not really accurate. Questions about research that happens outside of graduate education is also on topic, among other topics listed in the [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

The intent of the "undergraduate" close reason is to exclude questions on

> the folderol that is often very important for undergraduate life and has virtually nothing to do with academics (sports, underage drinking, living in dorms, being able to make your own choices for the first time, etc.)

(see [source](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1363/11365)).

It's not meant to apply to questions like the one you cite in your post, which just has nothing to do with universities or academia at all.  There is [no specific close reason](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/689/no-closing-reason-for-nothing-to-do-with-academia) for questions like this - that's what the "Other" option is for. Note that when you close a question as "Other," the text in the "put on hold as off-topic" box says

> This question does not appear to be about academics within the scope defined in the [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

which is *precisely* the reason the question is closed.